# Tmux can not exit

Tags: terminal, tmux

I just started to learn about Tmux today, I did 'ctrl' + 'b' then '%' to split my current screen but I can not exit the second window right now, I got this thing '<' at the beginning of each line. Where does it comes from and what should I d to exit it?

thank you!

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORdZo.png)

Answer (score 0):

You entered a ` so the shell (not tmux) is waiting for you to close it. Press ctrl-c to get back to the shell prompt.